# HTML5 <video> tag, onended event not working when using loop as attribute

Tags: html, angular, video, ionic2

I have a list of videos. I want to play a single video seven times. I have played it by eventListener but video is blinking when it goes end and play again.

So I added the loop attribute in the video tag.

```
<video id="video1" width="100%"  poster="img/aImg.png" style="height: 35vh;" autoplay  webkit-playsinline playsinline>
    <source src={{myVideo}} type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

But It is continuous playing video, I am not getting the video end event.

Please suggest for events to get the count of loop or video end event.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try so far and could you post your code?

Comment: And where is the onended event?

Comment: I would suggest tracking the timechanged event and if it skips back to `.currentTime < 1` (or similar) incrementing your counter. If the user has scrubber controls you may need to check it they initiated it, but you don't have that attribute in your code so hopefully one complexity not to worry about